# MsMq installation credentials

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

We have a problem with `MSMQ`.
The design is we have some server with msmq installed with user X.
Now we install some Windows Service with user y credentials. 
the problem is that the service can not reach or create a new private queue. we get the following exception :
`Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running, the queue exists and has proper authorization to be read from. The inner exception may contain additional information. An error occurred while opening the queue:Access is denied. (-1072824283, 0xc00e0025). The  message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the required access mode and authorization.   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.OpenQueue()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.GetHandle()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqQueue.SupportsAccessMode(String formatName, Int32 accessType, MsmqException& msmqException)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqVerifier.VerifyReceiver(MsmqReceiveParameters receiveParameters, Uri listenUri)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)`

our solution for now is removing the MSMQ and installing it with the user credentials of the service.
Any way to do this right ?

**UPDATE**

OK i have found the problem, service with user X credentials created a private queue ..
the service was removed and then installed again with user Y credentials .. the queue was not removed . so when user Y try to create or used the private queue it get a security exception.  is there any way to create the queue with predefined credentials ?

Comment: Try [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Have you tried giving the service user access to MSMQ or creating the queue manually and assigning the service user access?

Comment: The user is admin, so its a bit strange.